# Gdb assembly language instruction add

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to understand the add instruction in assembly code:

```
=> 0x08048bff <+43>:    add    0x14(%esp,%ebx,4),%eax
(gdb) i r
eax            0x1      1
ecx            0x0      0
edx            0x0      0
ebx            0x1      1
esp            0xffffcd70       0xffffcd70
ebp            0xffffcdc8       0xffffcdc8
esi            0x0      0
edi            0x0      0
eip            0x8048bff        0x8048bff <phase_2+43>
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x23     35
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x2b     43
es             0x2b     43
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x63     99
```

I think the answer for `0x14(%esp,%ebx,4)` is `(%ebx*4)+%esp+0x14` but what I got was `0xffffcd82` and I don't know what address that is from the registers. Can someone explain to be what value I'm supposed to put in `%eax`?

Comment: You need a manual describing the instructions of your CPU to understand that.

Comment: I guess the right question would be where do I look for the address 0xffffcd82 assuming I got the math correct in my memory? Is there an instruction in GDB that lets you look at memory? I'm trying to find out what the value is to figure out the line I'm on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right that `0x14(%esp,%ebx,4)` is at&t syntax for `(%ebx*4)+%esp+0x14`. As such, the address is `0xffffcd88`. You can have gdb calculate that for you using `p/x $ebx*4+$esp+0x14`. The `add` instruction will fetch the 4 byte integer in memory at that address and add it to whatever is already in `%eax`. You can check the memory contents in gdb using for example `x/d 0xffffcd88`.

PS: you can switch gdb to use intel syntax which should be easier to read using `set disassembly-flavor intel`.

Comment: Ah I see, you answered my question perfectly. Now I know the value in %eax is 1. Thanks!